# How can I use CASE expression with SUM function in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case

I have an Oracle SQL query that I need to select certain deduction codes and provide a predetermined amount if based on the premium amount for deduction code 91B.  These are hard coded values that I need to summarize.

```
SELECT SUM(DECODE(DEDCD,'91A',AL_AMOUNT,0)) MED91A,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DEDCD = '91B' THEN 
       DECODE(AL_AMOUNT, 23.54,7.85,
                         40.62,8.31,
                          43.85,8.31,
                          56.77,8.31,
                          AL_AMOUNT)) MED91B
    FROM PS_AL_CHK_DED 
    WHERE WEEK_NBR = 6
    AND TO_CHAR(CHECK_DT, 'YYYY')=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
```

The `SUM(DECODE ..)` statement used to summarize values where `dedcd = '91A'` works fine.  When I add the part to summarize values where `dedcd = '91B'` it produces a 'Missing Keyword' error after the decode statement.  I'm trying to streamline the query in order to produce the results I need for these two deduction codes because the full query takes entirely too long to run.

Oracle Sql Developer 4.0.2.15

Answer (score 1):

You must complete the **case expression** syntax with an **END** keyword.

Do it like this:

```
CASE WHEN DEDCD = '91B' THEN 
       DECODE(AL_AMOUNT, 23.54,7.85,
                         40.62,8.31,
                          43.85,8.31,
                          56.77,8.31,
                          AL_AMOUNT)
END
```

A basic case expression looks like:

```
CASE [ expression ]

   WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN condition_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) for more details.